# How do I Integrate RevenueCat to my flutter sample app?

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I am trying to explore the RevenueCat for in app purchase applications. I want to build a sample application which shows some products with purchases & subscriptions. Can I integrate the RevenueCat for my flutter sample application or do I need a real application to check that flow.

Comment: checkout their official doc,they explained how to integrate https://docs.revenuecat.com/v2.3/docs/flutter @Sravanthi

Answer (score 5):

In order to usefully test in-app purchasing code you have to have published the test app to Google Play or the App Store. So, yes, you need a 'real' app, even though it may only ever exist in 'internal testing' on the store.
You also have to do the testing on a physical device. This is true whether you use RevenueCat or another package.

Follow the RevenueCat docs and blogs and check the Flutter example app. The information they provide is very comprehensive. There are also a couple of good Medium articles that you can search for.

BTW, if your app will be monetized with renewable subscriptions rather than one off purchases, I suggest you stick with RevenueCat as the other Flutter packages currently don't help in that area. Been down that road :-)